# getBounds.contains doesn't work but a new Rectangle with get bounds as parameter does

Tags: java, intersection

So I have a question. I use code which checks if I am dragging a button unto a JLabel and I control it by asking for `label.getBounds().contains(pointWhereDraggingStopped)` which returns false whereas `new Rectangle(label.getBounds()).contains(pointWhereDraggingStopped)` is true. Any idea as of why it could be?

I would post code but its a mess. I mean I will just put rectangle to make it work just curious as of why would it consider it not contained like that. They are all added as components into a panel both the label and all buttons by the way.

```
 public void endOfDragging(Point pointOfEndOfDragging, Card draggedCard) {

    for (Component c : this.panel.getComponents()) {
        if (c.contains(pointOfEndOfDragging) && c.getName().equals("Button")) {
            return;
        }
        if (c.getName().equals("Brazier")) {
            System.out.println(pointOfEndOfDragging+ "///" + c.getBounds());
            System.out.println(new Rectangle(c.getBounds()).contains(pointOfEndOfDragging));
            System.out.println(c.contains(pointOfEndOfDragging));
        }
        if (c.getName().equals("Brazier") && new Rectangle(c.getBounds()).contains(pointOfEndOfDragging) && DraggedCard.getTyp() == TypeOfCard.SUMMONING) {
            DraggedCard.use((IFighter) DraggedCard);
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a mess, clean it up. You are clearly doing something else wrong, but we can't help you fix it without seeing code. If I could trust you to describe everything that is going on accurately, you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.

Comment: I guess that's a fair point, Ill work on cleaning it up and see where that brings me,

Comment: Okay,I've pasted the method where the error occurs in case

Comment: That's not very messy at all. Thanks for posting the code